# Estou fazendo um alert após 3 clicks e interromper os próximos clicks, mas quando desmarco algum que foi marcado o alert ainda aparece

Tags: javascript

Resumindo, tenho 10 botões e quero fazer escolha de apenas 3, se tentar clicar no 4° botão aparece um alert informando que excedeu o limite selecionado "Até aqui tudo bem, está funcionando meu código", mas se eu quiser desmarcar um botão selecionado para marcar outro, o alert ainda funciona e não deveria, aqui que esta meu erro no código.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obs: aqui no snippet não está funcionando, no meu local host está, não sei porque, talvez eu não soube configurar.

```js
function changeClass(clicked_id) {
  itemIndex = $("#div-megasena button.active-mega").length;
  if (itemIndex < 2) {
    classe = document.getElementById(clicked_id).className;
    if (classe == 'btn btn-outline-success') {
      document.getElementById(clicked_id).className = 'btn btn-success active-mega';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(clicked_id).className = 'btn btn-outline-success';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById(clicked_id).className = 'btn btn-outline-success teste';
    alert('Limite de numeros selecionados atingidos');
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="01" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">01</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="02" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">02</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="03" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">03</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="04" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">04</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="05" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">05</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="06" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">06</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="07" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">07</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="08" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">08</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="09" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">09</button>
<button onclick="changeClass(this.id)" id="10" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">10</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
```

Comment: Boa tarde... manda o seu codigo por completo, não achei o $("#div-megasena button.active-mega")

Answer (score 0):

Até pode ser feito usando o alert mas o resultado visual final não é bom pois o [botão bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/) possui algumas peculiaridades:

- Em dispositivo cujo a interação com a tela é controlada por mouse, o processo de animação de transição e troca de estados só se conclui ao ponteiro do mouse deixar o elemento. Um disparo dum alert, durante essa transição de estados, ocasiona um glitch(ao meu ver incontornável) onde transição de estado do botão no momento um que o alert é exibido é interrompida, fazendo com que o botão seja exibido como selecionado mesmo não estando selecionado. O glitch se corrige ao fechar o alert e passar o ponteiro do mouse sobre o elemento.
- Em dispositivo cujo a tela é touchscreen, o processo de animação de transição e troca de estados se conclui cronologicamente. Um disparo dum alert, durante essa transição de estados, ocasiona um glitch(ao meu ver incontornável) que interromperá e exibirá o botão como selecionado mesmo não estando selecionado. O glitch se corrige ao fechar o alert e clicar em outro botão.
- Em dispositivos cujo a interação com a tela é controlada por teclado o processo ocorre tranquilamente. Navegue entre os botões com a tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> e use tecla de <kbd>ESPAÇO</kbd> para selecionar ou descelecionar os botões.

```js
function changeClass(e) {
  if ($(".active-mega").length >= 3 &&
    $(e.target).hasClass("btn-outline-success")) {
    alert("Apenas três números podem ser selecionados.");
  } else {
    $(e.target).toggleClass("btn-outline-success btn-success active-mega");
  }
};

$(".btn").each(function(e) {
  this.addEventListener("click", changeClass);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="01" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">01</button>
<button id="02" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">02</button>
<button id="03" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">03</button>
<button id="04" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">04</button>
<button id="05" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">05</button>
<button id="06" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">06</button>
<button id="07" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">07</button>
<button id="08" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">08</button>
<button id="09" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">09</button>
<button id="10" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">10</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Uma alternativa para contornar esses glitches seria abandonar o `alert()` e utilizar o console para exibir uma mensagem.

```js
function changeClass(e) {
  if ($(".active-mega").length >= 3 &&
    $(e.target).hasClass("btn-outline-success")) {
    console.log("Apenas três números podem ser selecionados.");
  } else {
    $(e.target).toggleClass("btn-outline-success btn-success active-mega");
  }
};

$(".btn").each(function(e) {
  this.addEventListener("click", changeClass);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="01" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">01</button>
<button id="02" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">02</button>
<button id="03" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">03</button>
<button id="04" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">04</button>
<button id="05" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">05</button>
<button id="06" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">06</button>
<button id="07" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">07</button>
<button id="08" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">08</button>
<button id="09" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">09</button>
<button id="10" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">10</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Outra alternativa seria abandonar o `alert()` e usar um [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

```js
function changeClass(e) {
  if ($(".active-mega").length >= 3 &&
    $(e.target).hasClass("btn-outline-success")) {
    $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
  } else {
    $(e.target).toggleClass("btn-outline-success btn-success active-mega");
  }
};

$(".btn").each(function(e) {
  this.addEventListener("click", changeClass);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button id="01" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">01</button>
<button id="02" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">02</button>
<button id="03" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">03</button>
<button id="04" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">04</button>
<button id="05" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">05</button>
<button id="06" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">06</button>
<button id="07" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">07</button>
<button id="08" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">08</button>
<button id="09" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">09</button>
<button id="10" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">10</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Alerta!</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Apenas três números podem ser selecionados.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu não consegui fazer o seu codigo funcionar aqui... mas fiz algumas alterações no seu codigo, passei a usar jQuery e Eventos

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

    <button data-id="01" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">01</button>
    <button data-id="02" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">02</button>
    <button data-id="03" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">03</button>
    <button data-id="04" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">04</button>
    <button data-id="05" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">05</button>
    <button data-id="06" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">06</button>
    <button data-id="07" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">07</button>
    <button data-id="08" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">08</button>
    <button data-id="09" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">09</button>
    <button data-id="10" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">10</button>
</body>
<script>
    /* CONT BTNS SELECIONADOS */
    var wContMaxButtons = 0;
    /* EVENT MOUSEUP BUTTONS */
    $("button").on("mouseup", function () {
        var wClass = $(this).attr("class");
        var wIdBtn = $(this).attr("data-id");
        
        if (wClass == 'btn btn-outline-success') {
            if (wContMaxButtons == 5) {
                alert('Limite de numeros selecionados atingidos :(');
                return;
            }
            console.log("ID = " + wIdBtn)
            $(this).attr("class", "btn btn-success active-mega");
            /* INCREMENTA CONT */
            wContMaxButtons++;
        } else {
            console.log("ID = " + wIdBtn)
            $(this).attr("class", "btn btn-outline-success");
            /* DECREMENTA CONT */
            wContMaxButtons--;
        }

    });
</script>

</html>
```